# Linux routing manual/book/lecture/tutorial/videos for a Cisco guy

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm a Cisco CCNP who has moved from an ISP to a smaller company whit no Cisco equipments: using Linux boxes instead for routing and firewalling purposes.

Beside the fairly common configs of ip addressing, netmask and static routing, there are also some more complicated stuff like policy routing (a concept that I learned in the Cisco universe called PBR, Policy Based Routing).

I've tried to search for some good information about Linux networking but it seems that most of the stuff are a bit old'ish (before 2010):

Guide to IP Layer Network Administration with Linux [(1)](http://linux-ip.net/html/)

Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO [(2)](http://lartc.org/howto/index.html)

In your opinion, are these still valid and enough updated or are there best study and learning material?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From both the links  you provided , mostly talks of tools that be used in Linux Box for networking purpose . Most of the tools like

```
  iptables -  Linux firewall 
  tcpdump  - Packet Capturing tool
  arp  -> Managing ARP cache
  route -> Managing routes in a Linux host  
  mtr  --> network diagnostic tool 
  traceroute  --> Checking Packet route 
  netstat  --> Display network information
  tc --> manipulate traffic control settings
```

are still valid as of `RHEL 6`.

`zebra`  which turns a Linux box into a software based router is now `Quagga` and is still being maintained . There last release was in march , 16 .

http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/quagga/